# Feature Extraction from Images to use with LIBSVM

Tags: image, csv, classification, libsvm

I'm really stuck right now. I want to apply LIBSVM for Image Classification. I captured lots of Training-Images (BITMAP-Format), from which I want to extract features.

The Training-Images contain people who are lying on the floor. The classifier should decide if there is a person lying on the floor or not in the given Image.

I read lots of papers, documentary, guides and tutorials, but in none of them is documented how to get a LIBSVM-Package. The only thing that is described is how to convert a LIBSVM-Package from a CSV-File like this one: [CSV-File](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/spect/SPECTF.train). On the [LIBSVM-Website](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/datasets/) several Example-Data can be downloaded. The Example-Data is either prepared as CSV-Files or as ready-to-use Training- and Testdata.

If you look at the Values which are in the CSV-File, the first column are the labels (lying person or not) and the other Values are the extracted features, but I still can't reconstruct how those values are achieved.

I don't know if it's that simple that nobody has to mention it, but I just can't get trough it, so if anybody knows how to perform the feature extraction from Images, please help me.

Thank you in advance,
Regards

Answer (score 0):

You need to do feature extraction first. There are many methods that are available. These include LBP,Gabor and many more.. These methods will help you get the features to input into libsvm..Hope this helps...

Comment: Can you please provide additional details or links how to do it?